# How does a PHP global variable (i.e. $email) automatically get populated when a form is posted?

Tags: php, syntax

I came across a bit of code working in someone else's code for a form validator. It was supposed to return a value from the form data posted. Anyway, it was *always* returning `NULL`. This is what the function was in its entirety (the assumption is that this code *did* work at one point):

```
function _getValue($field)
{
    global ${$field};
    return ${$field};
}
```

From the context in the other functions, I could tell it was trying to get the value from the (in this case) $_POST variable. When I changed the function to the following, everything worked like a charm:

```
function _getValue($field)
{
    // $_REQUEST should hold $_GET and $_POST values
    return $_REQUEST[$field];
}
```

So my question is... what the heck is `global ${$field}` mean in this context? I know what `${$field}` is, but let's say they passed in `email` to that function. Where is this global `$email` variable coming from?

How is the original function supposed to have worked? I know there's something called "Super Globals" or something and that's bad. Is this related? Is that possibly why it stopped working? Did the host turn off Super Globals?

**[EDIT]** There was some obviously confusion in the way I phrased the question. I know what ${$field} and $$field means, but I don't know how

```
global ${$field};
return ${$field};
```

returns the value the user put into a form like

```
<input name="email">
```

when you call

```
$this->_getValue('email');
```

Comment: This belongs on The Daily WTF.  :-D

Comment: @Brad .. just The Daily PHP ;-)

Comment: @pst, Ha, I've seen a few decent projects done in PHP.  Just because there is a ton of bad PHP code doesn't mean the language is completely doomed.  But yes, I see what you are getting at.

Comment: My question is *not* related to the Variable Variables, but about how it gets from the form to a global variable or whatever.

Comment: Then see see [register globals](http://php.net/manual/en/security.globals.php) .. "This feature has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 5.3.0 and REMOVED as of PHP 5.4.0." :) Also consider updating the title to reflect this particular focus better.

Comment: @pst, "The Daily PHP" would *never* run out of content.

Comment: @Radu Sadly, "The Daily X", for *any* used programming language would never run out of content .. :-/

Comment: @Brad, it's not good coding but I wouldn't call it a WTF. At least, the programmer made a wrapper around the register_globals feature, so he only need to change `${$field}` to `$_REQUEST[$field]` once, without having to change it everywhere in the scripts.

Comment: @Laurent, Register globals on or off, that stuff is always in the $_REQUEST super global.  Very poor coding, plain and simple.  Unless this function is wrapped up in a class, any variable you can get with this function, you can get directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The programmer before you expected the POST variables to be in the global space, because of the [register_globals](http://php.net/manual/en/security.globals.php) directive. Thankfully, this feature has been turned off by default in PHP 4.2 and removed in PHP 5.4.

To quote the documentation:

> When on, register_globals will inject your scripts with all sorts of variables, like request variables from HTML forms.

I wonder how could anyone think that was a good idea :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is related to register_globals and yes it is very bad. I think you have fetched that from very old code. Now by default Php comes with register_globals set to off. That's why the code was not working. Your fix is correct. Register_globals is bad because it generates a serious security risk issue.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously got off track with my poor phrasing of the question, I apologize, but from the comments on Radu's post from Radu and pst, I found the following that answers my question perfectly (as found on http://php.net/manual/en/security.globals.php):

> **Note: Dealing with register_globals**
>
> If the deprecated [register_globals](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.register-globals) directive is set to ***on*** then the
>   variables within will also be made available in the  global scope of
>   the script. For example, `$_POST['foo']` would also exist as `$foo`.